# Nuxt generate show error: Cannot read property 'normalModuleFactory' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Recently I upgrade Nuxt from 1.4.0 to 1.2.x and Vuetify from 1.0.9 to 1.2.x. After that npm run dev works fine. but when I run Nuxt generate I get below error. I am stuck on this error since last night and can't find any idea why it's occurring. Any guidance will be helpful. Thank in advance.

```
nuxt:build Generating files... +138ms
nuxt:build Generating routes... +13ms
nuxt:build Building files... +314ms

ERROR

TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalModuleFactory' of undefined

- IgnorePlugin.js:96 IgnorePlugin.apply
[vue]/[webpack]/lib/IgnorePlugin.js:96:18

- Tapable.js:375 Compiler.apply
[npm]/[nuxt]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:375:16

- webpack.js:33 webpack
[npm]/[nuxt]/[webpack]/lib/webpack.js:33:19

- builder.js:524 compilers.compilersOptions.map.compilersOption
[npm]/[nuxt]/lib/builder/builder.js:524:24

- Array.map

- builder.js:523 Builder.webpackBuild
[npm]/[nuxt]/lib/builder/builder.js:523:39

- builder.js:168 Builder.build
[npm]/[nuxt]/lib/builder/builder.js:168:16
```

package.json can be find [here.](https://gist.github.com/napestershine/13cc52f22fb16b9f13572afc23733fa8)

nuxt.config.js can be found [here.](https://gist.github.com/napestershine/41efa934d8c24cd98518cd3033553213)

I tried to dig about it, but it seems to be generated through webpack. So I updated to webpack 4 too. But still it's throwing this error.

If you need any more details, I would be happy to provide.

Comment: Have you tried to remove node_modules folder and install all dependencies again?

Comment: Yes, I did it almost 3 times. but nothing get change

Comment: How do run it? Via command from.paxkage.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long talk with developer community of nuxtjs. Here is solution.
This problem occur when we try to run `nuxt generate` but our local nuxt version !== global nuxt version.

So solution is either update global nuxt version by `npm i -g nuxt` or run project from local nuxt version `node_modules/.bin/nuxt generate`

Comment: Why installing a global version anyway?